# How to add a fixed-position tooltip in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

My goal is to add an `HoverTool` to my figure which displays the weekday by name. The date is defined by the x-axis values. I want to display this information at a fixed position even if the visible section is changed by a tool like `BoxZoom`.

Since the HoverTool needs at least one renderer I first tried to define a line but I did not find a way to define the position relative to the figure. In fact if I zoom it can happen, that this line is not in the visible part and the HoverTool isn't working anymore (or in an area which is not visible).

My second attempt was to define an `extra_y_range` to draw the line relative. But I did not find a way to unselect the BoxZoom for this axis.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import (
    HoverTool, 
    LinearAxis,
    Range1d,
)
output_notebook()

dr = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-05', freq='D')

p = figure(title="line", plot_width=300, plot_height=300, x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x=dr, y=[6, 7, 2, 4, 5])
p.extra_y_ranges.update({"extra": Range1d(0, 1)})
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="extra", axis_label=''), "right")
l = p.line(x=dr, y=0.8, color='gray', **{"y_range_name":"extra"})


p.add_tools(
            HoverTool(
                tooltips=[("", "@x{%A}")],
                renderers=[l],
                mode="vline",
                formatters={"@x": "datetime"},
            ))
show(p)
```

[image: Display weekday by name]

Is there a way to add an HoverTool which stays at the same position in the visible area even if this area is effected by tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution which works for Bokeh v2.1.1. In the code below the tooltip is fixed at absolute position on the screen. You can add yourself more generic solution independent of the plot position on the screen.

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
import numpy as np

p = figure(plot_width = 300, plot_height = 300, tooltips = [('value X', '@x'), ('value Y', '@y')])
circles = p.circle(x=np.random.rand(10)*10, y=np.random.rand(10)*10, size=10)

callback = CustomJS(args={'p': p}, code="""
    var tooltips = document.getElementsByClassName("bk-tooltip");
    const tw = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < tooltips.length; i++) {
        tooltips[i].style.top = '5px'; 
        tooltips[i].style.left = p.width/2 - tw/2 + 'px'; 
        tooltips[i].style.width = tw + 'px'; 
    } """)

hover = p.select_one(HoverTool)
hover.renderers = [circles]
hover.callback = callback
hover.show_arrow = False

show(p)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: If I have multiple HoverTools, how can I apply this only to one HoverTools? Right now all Tooltips are modified.

Comment: Remove the `for` loop and use `tooltips[hover_index]` when `hover_index` is the index of the `HoverTool` that you have in mind e.g. `tooltips[3]`